# Symfony 2 validate a not required field but just has limited length

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, symfony

I tried to validate a not required field but just has limited length 0-50. But Symfony always generates required attribute as the following code. This makes user have to fill the required field. 
This is a server validation. Moreover, I also have a trouble with client validation because of the unwanted required attribute.

I wish a solution without using js. Does anybody know how to ignore attribute required that is generated by symfony? Please help me. Thank you

My case: I have a slug field. It is auto generated by field name (if slug is empty) or user can do that by himself.
In loadMetadata method, only 1 constraint for property slug

```
$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('slug', new Length(array(
        'min' => 0, 'max' => 50
    )));
```

Html output

```
<textarea id="category_slug" 
name="category[slug]" required="required" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

Doctrine mapping

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"}, unique=false)
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $slug;
```

Comment: sure. With js after page loading delete the required from your tag =)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But do you know other solutions without using js?

Comment: Does the `slug` property have any constraints in the entity file? If it's marked as `NotBlank`, you'll get the `required="required"` attribute.

Comment: I think your only option is to use JS, and as far as the symfony2 docs says, if required it's both on server and client side.

Comment: It has only one constraint Length and Doctrine mapping nullable=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your form is described in a form class, you can include this in the class:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Your\Bundle\Entity\Whatever',
        'required' => false,
    ));
}
```

#### Edit:

If you only want to affect a single field, do something like this in your form class:

```
->add('slug', null, array(
    'required' => false,
)
```

Comment: Thank you. But it also disables validation of other fields

Answer (score -2):

To disable the "required" on the field you need...

On your javascript document ready you can use this code:

```
$('#category_slug').removeAttr('required');
```

Comment: No. Instead of removing the attribute, you should prevent it from getting added in the first place.